# É uma boa prática ter o mesmo name com a coluna nome do banco?

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, pdo, modelagem

Digamos que eu tenha um `input text de name="txtnome"`, é uma boa pratica ter uma coluna de mesmo nome  que este `input` na minha tabela?

Sendo que eu estou usando PDO para o CRUD

```
$st =$this->db->prepare("UPDATE $tabela SET yxtnome=:txtnome WHERE id=:id");
$st->execute(array(
   ":id"=> $_POST["id"],
   ":txtnome" => $_POST["txtnome"]
 ));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode-se dizer que é. Se não causa problema é uma boa prática.

Mas como toda "boa prática", ela só é válida quando a pessoa sabe o que está fazendo. Quando a pessoa não entende porque aquilo está sendo adotado, está só repetindo o que os outros disseram pra ela fazer, sempre será uma má prática. Mesmo que esteja certo, se acertou por coincidência, é uma péssima prática.

A única boa prática de fato é entender o que está fazendo, estudar profundamente o mecanismo que está usando e analisar a situação específica para determinar se deve ou não adotar um determinado procedimento naquela situação real.

O objetivo da coluna do banco de dados é armazenar exatamente o que está no formulário da página? Então parece ser ok. Agora, se a coluna guarda um dado que possui uma relação com este campo da página, mas isto ocorre apenas por acaso, se esta coluna pode ter dados vindos de outros pontos da aplicação, ou seja, se a relação é indireta, então isto pode mudar de figura. Ou não, afinal há nomes que são muito comuns.

Algumas pessoas acham que usar o prefixo `txt` não é recomendável. É algo desnecessário. Isto é considerado [notação húngara](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota%C3%A7%C3%A3o_h%C3%BAngara) e desincentivado por ser algo supérfluo e eventualmente danoso quando precisa por alguma razão trocar o tipo do dado.

Pode ser que a arquitetura da aplicação, ao qual eu não conheço, possa ter alguma necessidade específica que torne isto uma prática ruim, mas não posso afirmar.

Mas note que tudo isto é muito conceitual. Tecnicamente não há nada que impeça ou cause problema. E talvez esta seja a real pergunta.

Já o `UPDATE $tabela` pode ser um péssima prática dependendo de onde vier esta variável. Seria pedir para sofrer um ataque potencialmente devastador no banco de dados. Mas isto não é o foco da pergunta.

Comment: tenho que criar 10 formulários com 40 questões cada (no meu código há um loop que pega a coluna name do $_POST e faz uma referência com a coluna da tabela de banco de dados), creio que perderia muito tempo verificando o form do html e a coluna do banco. o nome da tabela poderia ser de um variável private: UPDATE $this->tabela . existe um outro modo melhor de garantir melhor a segurança ?

Comment: Eu discordo. Os nomes dos controlos em nada devem influenciar o nome das colunas nem o reciproco. Não quer dizer que isto não possa acontecer. Isto ao fim ao cabo pode ser quase uma questão de convenção criada pela equipa de desenvolvimento. Mas por certo eu já desenvolvi várias aplicações onde não estou preocupado se o nome do elemento é ou não igual ao da base de dados.

Comment: @denalioasis então você precisa de melhores técnicas, ferramentas. Quanto a segurança eu não posso dizer porque não vi o todo, mas tirar essa variável seria uma boa.

Comment: @BrunoCosta obrigado por discordar sem discordar de nada.

Comment: @bigown. Mais concretamente discordo com o primeiro paragrafo.

Comment: @BrunoCosta se concorda com o segundo e terceiro parágrafo, já está joia, porque aí anula sua discordância do primeiro :)

Comment: @bigown `Pode-se dizer que é.` Na minha perspectiva nem é nem deixa de ser. `Se não causa nenhum problema, é uma boa prática.` Isto para mim é um grande começo para muitos problemas. Não é por causar nenhum problema que é uma boa prática certamente. Por exemplo eu posso chegar ao trabalho e não dizer bom dia a ninguem que em principio não me causa problemas, mas não é uma boa prática do ponto de vista social. Mas deixe estar, não interessa assim tanto.

Comment: Então você discorda na verdade dos parágrafos seguintes. Você acha que seguir uma convenção cegamente é algo bom. O exemplo fora da programação mostra bem isto. Você dá bom dia porque todo mundo dá, nunca se questionou porque faz isto. Então o que você está fazendo na verdade é uma má prática. Agora se você souber que dá bom dia porque as pessoas esperam isto, se você não fizer, você será mal visto e quando precisar de alguma coisa, terá dificuldades, aí você pensou, viu que a prática de não dar bom dia era ruim e decidiu fazer a boa.

Comment: Agora imagine que trabalhe em um lugar onde todo mundo odeie o bom dia. Se você o fizer, você estará causando problema para si mesmo, então seguiu a boa prática que achava que valia sempre e está se prejudicando. Obrigado por me dar a oportunidade de mostrar com seguir "boas práticas" é algo muito errado e fazer p certo em cada situação é a única opção correta. O resto é gosto.

Comment: Boa prática é sinônimo pra "me disseram que assim é bom, mas não sei o motivo". Programador precisa saber o motivo, e se não souber, tem que pesquisar e aprender o motivo, aí larga esse papo de boas práticas, que na minha experiência, quando a pessoa usa muito, reflete um tipo de profissional não tão confiável na maioria dos casos. Tou dando este toque, pq se o autor está aprendendo, e perguntou sobre boas práticas, deve ter ouvido o termo em algum lugar, então fica o alerta de "ficar esperto" com o termo duvidoso. Não seja mais um cara "das boas práticas", seja o cara do conhecimento.

Comment: Toda linguagem vem com "manual de boas práticas" e se chama documentação. Salvo casos quem que a convenção da linguagem exige especificamente algo (como o prefixo _ do Dart) tem que entender que boas práticas são universais - não dependem da linguagem ou método - e o principal é tornar o código mais legível possivel.